# Bootstrap columns col-md-* must not exceed 12

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap showning `"Sum of columns  col-md-* must not exceed 12 "`. I defined col-md-2 two times. that's it. What could be the problem?

```
   <div class="col-md-10" id="box_front_top">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.ActionLink(i18n_Models_Category.CategoryManagement, "Index", "Category", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary reset-a-visited" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-offset-1">
        @Html.ActionLink(i18n_General.ImageManagement, "Index", "Image", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary reset-a-visited" })
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a required `row` element:

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="box_front_top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting